# Run in OPEN Python-Idle from Notepad++

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, python-idle

Im using a shortcut in Notepad++ to Run my Python-files directly in Python IDLE. 
From the shorcut.xml, you can see how I'm using it:

```
<Command name="runinpython" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="81">&quot;C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw&quot; -r &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
```

The problem is: Every time I press `Shift+Alt+Q`, it opens another IDLE-Window and I'd like to  only open it once and then run my .py-files in it, otherwise I have to close the IDLE windows each time after every execution.

Do you know a way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://mpcabd.xyz/notepad-plugin-to-run-python-scripts/ supports it
-> when running py-scripts from within Notepad++, there won't be new console-windows opened all the time, but instead the script always runs in the open cmd-window :-)